# How to Webstorm search references acquired by jquery selectors?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, webstorm

when you use ctrl+g on a reference, it finds you that within the same file

is there a more global search (all files in project) that finds direct references as well as as those places where jquery is invoked to get a reference to the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the event that is occurring on any button or any html element when clicked.

All you need to do is instead of searching it right in the webstorm you can trace it accurately in the firebug.

Please make sure that firebug is installed or open the default developer's tool in your firefox or chrome browser.

To see the event that is occurring on an element :

> right  on the element and inspect it.
>
> firebug will open up at the bottom of the browser and in the right-bottom corner you will find a box in which there are different tabs.
>
> click on the events tab
>
> you will see events such as click,mousehover....etc.
> check the function that is getting called by clicking on that function name and it will show you the line of code that is being executed when you click that particular element with the js file name and the line number.

Hope that helps you out.

Comment: I'll try that out thanks, I was hoping I could do it in Webstorm as I am already using a handful of different desktop applications to develop and would prefer to minimize the number of tools I need. So I won't mark your answer as official just yet.

Comment: You can use Ctrl+left mouse click to trace the linking of the function. what you have to do is hover over the function name and then press ctrl+left click. it will show you the files in which that function exists.